# Inserting into table based on data in another table (SQL syntax)

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sql-insert

I hope I have the right group.  I did not see a separate group for SQL questions.  I have what I think and hope is an easy question. I've modified the tables (to protect work secrets) and I believe I have a simple, reproducible example.  The script to build the tables and populate some data is below.  I need a way to populate data in one table, based on another tables values.  This is for testing purposes.

I have three tables LoadingBay, Truck, and TruckMake.  Truck has a foreign key to LoadingBay: Truck.LoadingBayId -> LoadingBay.Id.   TruckMake just contains three rows 'Ford', 'GM' and 'Toyota' and for better or worse is not linked to any tables.

I have some data in LoadingBay.  For each and every LoadingBay row where Status='Empty', I'd like to add a Truck.  To put date in a LoadingBay, I've successfully used:

```
INSERT INTO LoadingBay  (Tall, Status) values (1, 'Empty') -- 1 means 'Tall Bay'
```

To put in a Truck, I then use:

```
INSERT INTO TRUCK (LoadingBayId, Make, Notes, BigEngine) values (1, 'Ford', 'Used Truck', 0)
```

Notice I have to put in the LoadingBayId by hand, and I need to do this for each truck.  Also notice that I put in 'Ford' and didn't reference the TruckMake Table.

I'd like to put in a truck for each loading bay and have tried various combinations of:

```
INSERT INTO TRUCK (LoadingBayId, Make, Notes, BigEngine) values (select from LoadingBay where Status = 'Empty')
-- and try this
INSERT INTO TRUCK (LoadingBayId, Make, Notes, BigEngine) values (select LoadingBayId from LoadingBay where Status = 'Empty', 'GM','Random Note',1)
```

to no avail.

Can someone tell me how to do this AND also replace the hardcoded 'GM' with a call to randomly pick a row from TruckMake and also pick just the first row (I'd like both options).

I have tried to research this, but have not found the answer.  It occurs to me that some sort of ForEach loop may be an option, but other sources have suggested that you shouldn't need this in SQL.  Instead one should think in terms of sets.

Please let me know if I can provide clarification or more material.  Apologies for the sloppy title.  I suspect if I could formulate a good title, I wouldn't have the question :)

Many thanks,

Dave
Here's the script to add the DB and populate it.  I'm using SQL Server Compact 4.0

```
-- Script Date: 3/8/2017 9:38 AM  - ErikEJ.SqlCeScripting version 3.5.2.64
-- Database information:
-- Locale Identifier: 1033
-- Encryption Mode: 
-- Case Sensitive: False
-- Database: C:\Andrew DBs\Play.sdf
-- ServerVersion: 4.0.8876.1
-- DatabaseSize: 128 KB
-- SpaceAvailable: 3.999 GB
-- Created: 3/8/2017 8:30 AM

-- User Table information:
-- Number of tables: 3
-- LoadingBay: 6 row(s)
-- Truck: 1 row(s)
-- TruckMake: 3 row(s)

CREATE TABLE [TruckMake] (
  [Id] int IDENTITY (4,1) NOT NULL
, [Make] nchar(100) NOT NULL
);
GO
CREATE TABLE [Truck] (
  [Id] int IDENTITY (3,1) NOT NULL
, [LoadingBayId] int NOT NULL
, [Make] nchar(100) NOT NULL
, [Notes] nchar(100) NULL
, [BigEngine] bit NOT NULL
);
GO
CREATE TABLE [LoadingBay] (
  [Id] int IDENTITY (7,1) NOT NULL
, [Tall] bit NOT NULL
, [Status] nchar(100) NOT NULL
);
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TruckMake] ON;
GO
INSERT INTO [TruckMake] ([Id],[Make]) VALUES (
1,N'Ford                                                                                                ');
GO
INSERT INTO [TruckMake] ([Id],[Make]) VALUES (
2,N'GM                                                                                                  ');
GO
INSERT INTO [TruckMake] ([Id],[Make]) VALUES (
3,N'Toyota                                                                                              ');
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TruckMake] OFF;
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Truck] ON;
GO
INSERT INTO [Truck] ([Id],[LoadingBayId],[Make],[Notes],[BigEngine]) VALUES (
1,1,N'Ford                                                                                                ',N'Used Truck                                                                                          ',0);
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Truck] OFF;
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [LoadingBay] ON;
GO
INSERT INTO [LoadingBay] ([Id],[Tall],[Status]) VALUES (
1,1,N'Empty                                                                                               ');
GO
INSERT INTO [LoadingBay] ([Id],[Tall],[Status]) VALUES (
2,1,N'Empty                                                                                               ');
GO
INSERT INTO [LoadingBay] ([Id],[Tall],[Status]) VALUES (
3,1,N'Empty                                                                                               ');
GO
INSERT INTO [LoadingBay] ([Id],[Tall],[Status]) VALUES (
4,1,N'Empty                                                                                               ');
GO
INSERT INTO [LoadingBay] ([Id],[Tall],[Status]) VALUES (
5,1,N'Empty                                                                                               ');
GO
INSERT INTO [LoadingBay] ([Id],[Tall],[Status]) VALUES (
6,1,N'Empty                                                                                               ');
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [LoadingBay] OFF;
GO
ALTER TABLE [TruckMake] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_TruckMake] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
GO
ALTER TABLE [Truck] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Truck] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
GO
ALTER TABLE [LoadingBay] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_LoadingBay] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
GO
ALTER TABLE [Truck] ADD CONSTRAINT [IXX_LoadingBay] UNIQUE ([LoadingBayId]);
GO
```